# Composition of Injective and Surjective maps?

Tags: number-theory

Consider a composite $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x))$ of two maps $X \xrightarrow{g} Y \xrightarrow{f} Z$.
If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, what is the results of the composition $f \circ g$? [or DNE if it does not always have one of these properties]

Similarly, bijective and surjective, AND bijective and injective?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the definition of each? Just trying to see if you know what each mean.

Comment: why did you tag it with number theory?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that LaTeX is the preferred way to write Maths here. Take a look at the editing I did on your question to see some details. Also, one expects to see some kind of progress you have done on your questions. Have you tried constructing examples?

Answer (score 2):

A hint on your first question. Try and take $X = Z = \{1, 2\}$ and $Y = \{3\}$.

For your other questions, try some examples, and then decide whether you want to prove something.